# Why `string` `vector` etc does not work in union in bison?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison, yacc, lex

I was trying to write a parser for a subset of C language . But when I include `string`  or `vector` inside the `%union` , it throws error . Using `char*` or `array`  seems to be fine .

```cpp
%union{
    string s;
    vector<int>v;
}
```

I have seen in some place that it is related to a header issue where they suggest to do include this

```cpp
%code requires{
    #include <string>
}
```

for string case . but this also does not work for me .

The error i get is

```cpp
y.tab.c:1174:9: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::YYSTYPE()’
 YYSTYPE yylval;
         ^~~~~~
y.tab.c:223:7: note: ‘YYSTYPE::YYSTYPE()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union YYSTYPE
       ^~~~~~~
demo.y:48:12: error: union member ‘YYSTYPE::s’ with non-trivial ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
     string s;
            ^
demo.y:49:16: error: union member ‘YYSTYPE::v’ with non-trivial ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector() [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
     vector<int>v;
                ^
y.tab.c: In function ‘int yyparse()’:
y.tab.c:1203:30: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::YYSTYPE()’
     YYSTYPE yyvsa[YYINITDEPTH];
                              ^
y.tab.c:1203:30: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::~YYSTYPE()’
y.tab.c:223:7: note: ‘YYSTYPE::~YYSTYPE()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union YYSTYPE
       ^~~~~~~
demo.y:48:12: error: union member ‘YYSTYPE::s’ with non-trivial ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::~basic_string() [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
     string s;
            ^
demo.y:49:16: error: union member ‘YYSTYPE::v’ with non-trivial ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::~vector() [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
     vector<int>v;
                ^
y.tab.c:1203:30: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::~YYSTYPE()’
     YYSTYPE yyvsa[YYINITDEPTH];
                              ^
y.tab.c:1215:11: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::YYSTYPE()’
   YYSTYPE yyval;
           ^~~~~
y.tab.c:1215:11: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::~YYSTYPE()’
y.tab.c:1381:14: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE& YYSTYPE::operator=(const YYSTYPE&)’
   *++yyvsp = yylval;
              ^~~~~~
y.tab.c:223:7: note: ‘YYSTYPE& YYSTYPE::operator=(const YYSTYPE&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 union YYSTYPE
       ^~~~~~~
demo.y:48:12: error: union member ‘YYSTYPE::s’ with non-trivial ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’
     string s;
            ^
demo.y:49:16: error: union member ‘YYSTYPE::v’ with non-trivial ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = int; _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]’
     vector<int>v;
                ^
y.tab.c:1412:24: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE& YYSTYPE::operator=(const YYSTYPE&)’
   yyval = yyvsp[1-yylen];
                        ^
y.tab.c:1569:14: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE& YYSTYPE::operator=(const YYSTYPE&)’
   *++yyvsp = yyval;
              ^~~~~
y.tab.c:1713:14: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE& YYSTYPE::operator=(const YYSTYPE&)’
   *++yyvsp = yylval;
              ^~~~~~
y.tab.c: In function ‘void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)’:
y.tab.c:1174:9: error: use of deleted function ‘YYSTYPE::~YYSTYPE()’
 YYSTYPE yylval;
         ^~~~~~
```

Comment: That's not a Bison limitation. You can't have a union containing a string and a vector in C++ period.

Comment: why is that the case ?